# Youtube video not playing

Tags: wireless, youtube

I use a wi-fi home network. My friends windows computer is able to play youtube videos with his windows machine in the same network. And I am able to play youtube videos using my iPhone's 3g network using my ubuntu machine. So, it seems my browser works fine.

```
$ cat /etc/resolve.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

I enabled html5 using `youtube.com/html5`

I restarted nscd,

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart
```

I restarted the computer and the modem several times, however the problem still remains. In the home-wifi-network, I am not able to play the youtube video.

Youtube webpage opens, everything is fine, however the video does not play. `ping youtube.com` works fine.

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 13.04,

Browsers: Firefox, chromium, google-chrome

Answer (score 1):

1: The file (actually a symbolic link) `/etc/resolve.conf` should be named `/etc/resolv.conf`.  Make sure it is a symbolic link to `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`.

2: Disable the NetworkManager-controlled local forwarding nameserver. Edit NetworkManager.conf

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

and comment out the line `dns=dnsmasq`

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

and then restart NetworkManager.

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

Ref: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dnsmasq/+bug/1003842

Comment: I am somehow unable to reproduce the bug right now.. And I don't remember what has fixed the problem..